# Difference between "repress" and "quell"

Tags: meaning, differences, synonyms

What is the difference in meaning between *repress* and *quell*?

Are they interchangeable?

Comment: Not in most cases.

Comment: Inadequate background research effort.

Comment: @Kris Their definitions seem extremely similar:

`put an end to (a rebellion or other disorder), typically by the use of force.` / `subdue (someone or something) by force.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that *repress* has more negative connotations than *quell*. One might "brutally repress an uprising", for example: it suggests that force (or similar severe methods) are used. "Quell" is more suggestive of gentle reassurance or reasoned argument: "the priest quelled their fears".

Linked to that, there's an implication that something "repressed" doesn't really go away; it's just no longer in the open. "Quell" suggests that issues have been smoothed over.

Comment: Good points, but there _is_ an area of overlap (ie the words are synonyms).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Indeed.

Comment: Interesting reversal because the etymology is just the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

Repress: "to check, restrain," ... "hold back, curb," figuratively "check, confine, restrain, refrain," ...- "back" (see re-) + premere "to push" A terms later associated with psychological repression, and arresting a rebellion -http://www.etymonline.com/

Whereas, quell was from the get go "to kill, murder, execute".